# Execute unix command and qsub jobs through perl

Tags: perl

I have a file (scripts.out) with list of commands. I need to split this file into multiple files and simultaneously submit each of it as qsub job. I am able to split the file but cannot do the 'qsub' . My code so far :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $outfile = "scripts.out";
my $split_command=`split -l 4  -d $outfile test_sub`;
my@split_array = split(/\n/,$split_command);
   foreach my$split_file (@splt_array) {
    `qsub $split_file`;
   }
```

I am sure there is a better way of doing it.
The split command generates following output files which needs to be 'qsub':

```
test_sub00
test_sub01
```

Please share your suggestions to improve the code; or an alternate way of doing it if possible.

Comment: It sounds to me like you should tackle the problem at its source. Why does `scripts.out` contain all of the submission scripts in the first place? I use perl to submit jobs using `qsub`. I generate the submission script (which is largely boilerplate) and submit the jobs in the same loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your my @split_array line to

```
my @split_array = glob "test_sub*";
```

As mentioned by toolic, the split command does not return a list of generated files.